# What set of compiler, sdk, targetsdk and tools settings will make android studio happy?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I got an email from google saying I had to update my targetsdk settings to be at least 26 by november 2018.
So having waited almost 2 years I finally tried to switch to android studio from eclipse where I come to realized we've just traded one set of known problems to another set of unknown problems. I purposefully waited to migrate so everybody else could suffer the bleeding-edge-everything-is-broken problems and in fact every problem I run into has a stack overflow response except this one:

the compilesdk version has to be the same as the support library.

the compilesdk version should not be lower than the targetsdkversion.

the targetsdk version and the compiler version should be the latest which is 28 at the moment

But there's no appcompat past 26.0.0-beta1 as far as I can tell so it's impossible to satisfy all of the requirements as far as I can tell.
What are you actually supposed to do?

Comment: `there's no appcompat past 26.0.0-beta1` thats not true . You might wanna post your gradle . See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages or similar docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android Pie has been released a few days ago, I would wait for a stable Android Studio 3.2 release, because it has several refactoring options like migrating support lib to androidX etc. - so then you can go on with compileSdk and targetSdk 28 and also refactor the support libs to androidX (which will be necessary anyway). You can try that already with [Android Studio 3.2 Beta](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) but do not forget to raise the gradle version to at least 3.2-beta05 too, otherwise you might get unexpected errors, especially with migration of the old support libs.

Edit: If your current project is not even targeting API lvl 26, you'll probably have a lot of work to do anyway (depends on the features you use from the android sdk), imho it would be the best to go through the ["behavior changes"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) articles first (brought for each new android version) to know how it may affect your app. So if you want to test it as quick as possible, simply use the current Android Studio version (3.1.4), raise target- and compileSDK to 28 and also the [support libs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0-rc01). then, as soon as Android Studio 3.2 (and gradle plugin 3.2.0) is released, you can take advantage of the migrating feature for AndroidX. But for now, you should be more worried about the behaviour changes caused by the SDK update and not AndroidX. My first suggestion was just to wait for the android studio update to do that all in one step, instead of being annoyed at the next release when app compat will be deprecated.

Comment: any idea how long that's going to be? production software in general is broken enough, I'm not going to waste time using something advertised as known-broken ("beta").  I was hoping to get through this little nightmare this week. So I guess I'll have to do it twice anyway. Thanks for the info.

Comment: now that you mention it, this sounds very apple-like. Just like the language spec of objective-C  is defined by the version of the OS it came with (which just seems bizarre to me) it sounds like the same thing here, where the version of the tools you use is defined by the release of the IDE. This just seems wrong to me, but clearly the trillion dollar company knows better than I do.

Answer (score 1):

There are appcompat libraries released after *26.0.0-beta1*. The latest one is *28.0.0-rc01*.

Use these:

- compileSdkVersion 28
- targetSdkVersion 28 and
- implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'

You can actually check for the latest version of appcompat [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7?repo=google)

These are the latest. Feel free to ask me if there's anything else.

Comment: okay so my next question then is why doesn't the sdk manager install the newer versions of appcompat?

Comment: thanks for the maven link. So I put the dependency in my gradle file, and gradle seems happpy, but I notice it doesn't end up in ./extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/

Comment: @stu If a new version is out, and you update the repository through your sdk manager, studio will highlight that there is a newer version available, in your gradle file. When an update comes out they give a msg when you open studio. I have made it a hobby to check it manually at least once a month. As for your 2nd question, the downloaded files ends up in build-tools. build-tools is for the most recent downloaded version of the Build Tools SDK. Extras are basically extras for each version. Both are different things. I believe any further questions will be way off topic, and probably redundant.

Comment: that's the thing, I update everything there is to update in android studio and it doesn't indicate anywhere that there's something new. I will play more, thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand, if you've updated everything, what exactly are you looking for then?

Comment: I apparently was looking in the wrong place, I expected the appcompat libraries to show up in extras where all the other ones up to 26.0.0-beta1 are